# Android android.widget.ImageView setCropToPadding() get around

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview, android-gridview

I got this error `setCropToPadding() NoSuchMethodError` when running my app on version < 4.1. How do I set cropToPadding to the image loaded to a GridView cell without ImageView XML?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://gist.github.com/mrmans0n/2924241) to be the best answer for my issue... for now. Copy and paste over and it simply worked!

```
try {
    Field field = ImageView.class.getDeclaredField("mCropToPadding");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(imageView, true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Reference:  https://gist.github.com/mrmans0n/2924241

Answer (score 0):

`setCropToPadding()` was introduced in API level 16 (JellyBean). Look at the top right: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setCropToPadding(boolean)

Comment: You can try using setScaleType instead. I imagine one of the options will be suitable for your needs.

Comment: i did use setScaleType Center.CROP which introduce the need for setCropToPadding() for my gridview.